# PHP not updating rows in Database

Tags: php, mysql

What am I doing wrong here. I can't figure out how to make the Update block work. When I hit "Update" button, it goes back to edit.php but with

> errors. Errors are: Notice: Undefined variable: POST in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\libSys\edit.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\libSys\edit.php on
>   line 46
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\libSys\edit.php on
>   line 48

Successfully Updated

Lines 45, 46, 48 has

```
        echo $author = $POST['author']; //line 45
        echo $isbn = $POST['isbn']; //line 46

        $sql = "UPDATE booklist SET Author='$author', Title='title', ISBN = '$isbn' WHERE ID = '$id' ";  //line 48
```

The complete code of edit.php are below:

```
<?php
include('databaseConnection.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/librarySystem.css">
    <title> Edit Book Information </title>
</head>

<div>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit']))   //FIRST IF
{

    $id = $_REQUEST['edit'];
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM booklist WHERE ID=$id";
    $result=mysql_query($sql_select);

    // collect all the data using mysql_fetch_array and assign to our $variables

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $title = $row['Title'];
        $author= $row['Author'];
        $yearLevel = $row['YearLevel'];
        $isbn = $row['ISBN'];
    }

    //displays form for user to edit book information
    echo "<form method='POST' action='edit.php'>";
        echo "Enter New or Correct Title: <input type='text'  name='title'  value='$title' >  <br />";
        echo "Enter New or Correct Author: <input type='text'   name='author'  value='$author'> <br />";
        echo "Enter New or Correct ISBN: <input type='text'  name='isbn'  value='$isbn' >  <br / >";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Update' > <br />";
    echo "</form>";
}    //END 1st IF

else if( isset($_POST['save'] ) )    
{

        echo $title = $_POST['title'];
        echo $author = $POST['author'];
        echo $isbn = $POST['isbn'];

        $sql = "UPDATE booklist SET Author='$author', Title='title', ISBN = '$isbn' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($result == true)
            {
                echo "Successfully Updated" ;
            }
                //header('Location: ./booklist.php'); 
}

?>
```

How can I correct the update block. It seems to be going to the if(isset($_POST['save']) when I hit "Update" but won't really update the row. Please help. I'm stuck. I don't understand why the "Undefined variable" error pops when I have the variables assigned with $_POST['author']...

I'd appreciate any help or explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection. You're also using deprecated `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `super global` variables as `$_POST[]`

```
 echo $author = $_POST['author'];
 echo $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
```

Before updated into database use `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
$author=mysql_real_escape_string($author),
$isbn=mysql_real_escape_string($isbn));

 $sql = "UPDATE `booklist` SET Author='".$author."', Title='title', ISBN = '".$isbn."' WHERE ID = $id";
```

**Note**

`mysql` is deprecated instead use `mysqli OR PDO`

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't find the error on the form. The only problem now is line 48. I don't know why it can't recognize the value of id. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: create a hidden field in your form `echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' > <br />";` and get your id as ` $id = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: thank you for your help. I just started learning PHP a few days ago and still getting myself familiar of the syntax. All the answers from stackoverflow community is definitely helping me learn faster. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
echo $author = $POST['author'];
 echo $isbn = $POST['isbn'];
```

to

```
echo $author = $_POST['author'];
echo $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error, you use $POST instead of $_POST.

```
 echo $author = $_POST['author']; //line 45
 echo $isbn = $_POST['isbn']; //line 46

 $sql = "UPDATE booklist SET Author='$author', Title='title', ISBN = '$isbn' WHERE ID = '$id' ";  //line 48
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for php POST global variable is `$_POST` not `$POST` that you are using.

And I guess you are getting `$id` from a form using `$_GET` or `$_POST` method only.
So check out those syntaxes as well.

Comment: my bad. A typo error there. However, I can't find the error on the form. The only problem now is line 48. I don't know why it can't recognize the value of id. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: one more type mistake @jordan . You didn't close double quotes before `$id` in a sql statement. Try rewriting the statement with proper syntax.

Comment: the query could be like `$sql = "UPDATE booklist SET Author='".$author."', Title='title', ISBN = '".$isbn."' WHERE ID = ".$id;`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in the code. Firstly, $_POST is a superglobal in php. Superglobals start with a dollar sign and an underscore. You forgot the underscore that's why it's undefined. 
rewrite as:

```
echo $author = $_POST['author'];
echo $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
```

Secondly, you're using the $id variable inside the quotes. Rewrite line 48 as:

`$sql = "UPDATE booklist SET Author='{$author}', Title='title', ISBN = '{$isbn}' WHERE ID = '{$id}' ";  //line 48`

To use variables inside quotes without concatenation, you can use the '{' bracket. Keep in mind though, you can't do the same with constant values. Hope this helps :)